Android Service with Telephony Manager Implementation in Clean Architecture
Where does Service  belongs to in clean architecture package structure?
I created a service pkg under presentation layer, is it the the correct approach? Also in service I have a Telephony Manager which I need to register and create a separate class for that to implement methods:
private class TelephonyCallbackForStateListener extends TelephonyCallback
        implements TelephonyCallback.DisplayInfoListener,
        TelephonyCallback.ActiveDataSubscriptionIdListener,
        TelephonyCallback.SignalStrengthsListener {
        
}

Under which pkg I should Keep that class? Also as it is a system application there is no view so how to use the ViewModel in that case?
Also In case of SignalStrengthsListener callback I have to make some operation which involve counter. Where should I keep that counter file?
